# Powershell: Haskell-like $ (apply) operator?

Tags: powershell, syntax

I very often begin to type azure commands, then need to accesss a property, ending up with commands like

```
(($a|get-something).prop1|get-otherstuff).prop2
```

is there an elegant way (or hack) to write it more like haskell to avoid having to jump to the beginning of the line for the opening paranthesis? i am thinking of

```
$a | get-someArray $ [0] | get-details $ .prop2
```

For `.`-accessible properties, i got this far:

```
function $ {param([parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $x, [parameter(Position=1)]$y)$x|Select-Object -ExpandProperty $y}
```

allowing me to do `expr |$ prop | expr |$ prop` instead of `((expr).prop) | expr).prop`.

For array access, we can do

```
function § {param([parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] $x, [parameter(Position=1)]$y)$x[$y]}
```

Thus, we can get this far: `arrayexpr |§ 0 |$ prop`

Do you have more ideas to spare us from thinking ahead of typing?

Comment: like, do any ideas come to mind to hack tab completion into this?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know Haskell all that well, but

```
$a | Get-Something | % prop1 | Get-OtherStuff | % prop2
```

perhaps?

It's prone to breakage, of course, and you may still need parentheses to clarify which results are grouped in what way. But `ForEach-Object` is a convenient way to access property values via the pipeline, much more so than `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`.

Comment: oh wow, until now i thought % requires a scriptblock, ending up with %{$_.Prop}. Thanks

Comment: I think that variant was added in PowerShell 3 or 4. Took me a while to notice as well :)

Comment: There are two forms of [`Foreach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), one taking a script block and the other one taking a string. `|% member` is shorthand for `Foreach-Object -MemberName "member"`. This new form was added in PowerShell 3.0; prior to that it did only take a script block.